# Сustom data upload hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote a simple code that requests data from a local json server when the page loads. I have this code repeated in several places and I want to put it in the custom hook.

Tell me how to write and apply a custom hook correctly?

```
  const [data, setData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
      try {
        setData(await getData('http://localhost:3001/posts'))
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR >>', error.message)
      }
    }
    getPosts()
  }, [])
```

I tried to write like this, but it doesn't work:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { getData } from './../helpers'

const useData = url => {

  const [currentData, setCurrentData] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCurrentData = async () => {
      try {
        setCurrentData(await getData(url))
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR >>', error.message)
      }
    }
    getCurrentData()
  }, [url])
  
  return currentData
}

export default useData
```

Comment: You need to explain how it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Really everything works. For some reason I wrote this using destructurization `const {data} = useData(URL)` ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this sandbox, this seems to load data once every page loads. I just don't pass the URL inside `useEffect` because I only want to call it once on page load.

https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-sky-6fs4rq?file=/src/useData.jsx